# Recording of iPad (iOS 6) application using JMeter

Tags: ios, performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

In one of my project I came across in the situation that I need to conduct performance testing of an iPad application using JMeter for that essential thing is to record iPad (iOS 6) application using JMeter.

Things I have tried-

1. Setup HttpProxy in jmeter (port- 8080) before recording
2. Connected iPad with JMeter machine using WIFI
3. Setup proxy settings on iPad i.e. IP- Machine IP on which JMeter is installed port-8080
4. Start recording

After all above setup when I launch the application on iPad i'm facing issue "Unable to connect XYZ server " 
 -> where XYZ is the IP of VM on which JMeter is installed

If i'm doing other things on iPad i.e. opening the safari browser, launching other build in app, then in JMeter all these things gets captured except the testing application.

I have also installed JMeter certificate "JMeter Proxy (DO NOT TRUST)" on iPad but still same issue.

Please let me know, if anyone can help me in implementing same or came across such kind of  scenario.

Comment: Does we need to install any Jmeter certificate on iPad? because on Neoload a certificate needs to installed on iPad before recording

Comment: Anyone came across such kind of scenario, if yes please respond